# iOS 7 Autolayout doesn't work

Tags: ios, autolayout

I've been working today on this problem for a while now and i couldn't solve it. I downloaded Apple's Autolayout Guide and couldn't find an answer/solution. The problem is that I'm adding a `UIImageView` to my View Controller and when I change the `window`s form factor from 3.5 to 4 and vise versa, the `image view` is stretched.

To solve this, I tried many ways such as clicking on reset to suggested constraints, clear all constraints, and build my own constraints by pinning and aligning.

By aligning and pinning I set the `height` and `width` to the size as in the Interface Builder and the `horizontal` and `vertical` positions as well. Unfortunately, the image still stretches upon changing the form factor in Interface Builder. I tried to only pin the `height` of the `UIImageView` but it doesn't work.

How can i work this out?

Comment: What is the image size? Try creating the image for 4" display then turn the autolayout on and it will work for 3.5"

Comment: the image view is supposed to be 240 x 203 in size and the image is 480 x 406 since targeting retina (hence, double the size). the thing is i want the same sizes for both 4" and 3.5" and i want the UIImageView to be pinned even if i changed the screen size.

Comment: Might be silly but just make sure you haven't created too many constraints - for example, if you've pinned the vertical position from the top and the vertical position from the bottom, this may override your height constraint and cause it to stretch on resize.

Comment: Turn off the autolayout. Apply the anchors in IB. Then turn it on again and see if that works for you.

Comment: i thought the same thing, the removed all the constraints, pinned the width and height and added the vertical and horizontal constraints (thus, 4 constraints added) and non are conflicting and it's still stretching it

Comment: @XCodeMonkey still there. thanks anyway for the input.

Comment: What you're describing should be happening, and doesn't when I try it. Are you getting any warnings in the console when you run the app? Are you sure you don't have a constraint to the top and bottom of the view? What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: i'm using Xcode 5.0.2 and there is no warning. this is really weird! i wish autolayout wasn't there! now i have to be concerned about them and not about the code.

Answer (score 0):

Autolayout only deals with the frame/bounds of the `UIImageView`. The actual way the image is rendered is controlled via it's contentMode property. You need to set it to either `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` or `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill` to avoid stretching.

Comment: isn't there a way to keep the UIImageView frame pinned to a specific height and width even if i changed the factor form (screen size)?